# Confusing cont. r.v. problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Let $X_1$, $X_2$, $X_3$, $X_4$, $X_5$ be independent continuous random variables having a common
distribution function $F$ and density function $f$, and set

$$I = \mathbb{P}\{X_1 < X_2 < X_3 < X_4 < X_5\}$$
(a) Show that I does not depend on $F$.

(b) Evaluate $I$.

So far I've set a I = to 5-dimensional integral and have substituted ui with Fi, found that I's value is 2/15. Which makes me confused as to what is being asked, and where i'm going wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's $\mathbb{P}(X_1 < X_2 < X_3 < X_4 < X_5)$ compared to, say, $\mathbb{P}(X_2 < X_1 < X_3 < X_4 < X_5)$? Or $\mathbb{P}(X_{i_1} < X_{i_2} < X_{i_3} < X_{i_4} < X_{i_5})$ for any permutation of $i$ of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$? Use your intuition. How many such permutations are there? Then use the fact that $X_i$ is continuous to deduce that these events together have probability $1$.

Comment: is it 1/120 because 5! possibilities so since each has same prob. because they're independent r.v =>  1/5!

Comment: Yes, you got it.